# Android studio error code 500 URL:http://10.0.2.2:8081? index.delta?.... while react native run

Tags: react-native, android-studio-3.1.3

I'm absolutely new to react native. I installed react native and android studio as instructed in react native website -> Getting Started. But when I run the very basic react native app in my system I got the error as attached the image. How to make it work successfully without error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5948U.png)

I'm using
Android studio Version -> 3.1.3
JDK -> 8. something (exactly don't know. sorry)
Phython 2.7.15

Please help me.

Thanks,
Guru

Answer (score 0):

remove this line `type Props = {};`

And replace `Component<props>`   with `Component` and run again

This sintext is not needed in .js file it is allowed in .ts file so

**Update**

Down grade the react-native version and it will solve your problem

So go to your project directory and find file `package.json`

Inside the file you can find

```
"dependencies:{
     ....
  "react-native": "^0.56.0",
   ......
}
```

Change this `"react-native": "^0.56.0",`
 to `"react-native": "^0.55.4",`

Save the file

Go to the terminal and run command `npm-install`

After installation restart project and run again

Comment: Hi Jay,Thanks for your quick reply. After done that also getting same error.

Comment: I closed and re opened VS and ran again. No positive result. :(

Comment: Any solution? please help

Comment: run application using terminal command react-native run-android   and check the error in node terminal and show me what it is

Comment: Hi Jay, Thanks again. I have attached it in the main post. Please have a look and help me how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks you Jay. Let me try it and come back. Hope this will resolve it :)

Comment: Hi Jay, I have tried as u mentioned. But this time I'm getting different error. 1st I got like AccessibityInfo but this time like TransformError . I followed the points ->  1. Changed in dependencies as "react-native": "^0.55.4" 
2. in the terminal run d:/>proj_folder>npm install
3. Once installed I closed the VS code and re-opened
4. In the terminal run react-native run-android.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: check this link     https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14209

Comment: Thanks Jay. Let me check it.

Comment: Hi Jay, Thanks a lot for the link given to me. Finally I got solution to make it work with yours and some other comments from the other post by divyakoshy commented on Aug 19, 2017 -> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15559